# Estimation of probability with a loggamma distribution

Tags: python, density-function

I have an empirical observation with about 300K continuous values. I fitted these values (with disfit python library) getting a loggamma distribution:
[image]
The resulting parameters are:

- c = 0.08513733275923194
- loc = 4.422783357274778e-06
- scale = 2.430755669784885e-07

I want to estimate the probability of observing certain values of $x$, then so I coded a proof-of-concept:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import loggamma

>>> c = 0.08513733275923194
>>> loc = 4.422783357274778e-06
>>> scale = 2.430755669784885e-07

>>> x= -0.000001

>>> print( loggamma.pdf(x, c, loc, scale) )
>>> print( loggamma.cdf(x, c, loc, scale) )

54747.465342747964
0.1563094678919458
```

If my interest is to estimate the probability of $x$, what should be the interpretation of the results of the above? I mean, for the cdf, I understand that the result near $0.16$ is the probability of having a value equal to or less than $x=-0.000001$. However, does not make sense to me the result of the pdf does. If the result is a frequency value, should I divide it by the sample size? Sorry, I'm not a statistician.

Comment: Why are you fitting a distribution at all?  With so much data, why not just use their empirical distribution?

Comment: @whuber It's possible? I just only need to get the probability of $x$ but I don't know how to deal with when such $x$ value isn't in my data, so I figure that if I know what distribution my data follows then I can calculate it.

Comment: The *empirical distribution* is the distribution exhibited by your data.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=empirical+distribution+function+ecdf for relevant posts and illustrations.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber! I just encoded the ecdf of my sample data and got good results, very close to the theoretical loggamma distribution. Just to know, in my post, what does the $54747.465342747964$ result of the pdf calculation mean for $x=-0.000001$? I expected a value between $0$ and $1$

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220